# How do I prove the equivalence between surjectivity or injectivity and existence of one sided inverse functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having a problem with a three piece exercise.

It goes like this: 
a) Show that there exists a function $g$ such that $f\circ g = I$ if and only if $f$ is surjective.

b) Show that there exists a function $h$ such that  $h\circ f = I$ if and only if $f$ is injective.

c) If $f\circ g =  f\circ h = I$, is it always true that $g = h$?

Here $I$ is the identity function and all functions go from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I think the first two make perfect sense but I have no idea how to effectively show the implications towards the existence of a function.

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: Try to go step by step, one implication at a time, working from/towards the definitions. So for part a, start by assuming such g exists. Now use that g to show surjectivity, ie take an arbitrary y and write down x such that f(x)=y.

Comment: I really am not seeing how to do this. Maybe I don’t know all the definitions, but I really don’t even know what would be missing

Comment: I just gave you the definition of surjectivity. Suppose you have functions f and g and a real number y, and that f(g) = I. Find x such that f(x)=y. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you can't get the formality, maybe start by writing in sentences why it "makes perfect sense"

Comment: Oh, thank you. I knew those definitions, I just was taking the functions in the opposite order and it wasn’t making sense

Comment: Ok, so my argument was that if $f\circ g$ and $I$ are identical, for every $y\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y = (f\circ g)(x) = I(x)$ which implies that $f(g(\mathbb{R})) = I(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$. We also have that $g(\mathbb{R})\subset \mathbb{R}$ which, together with the previous statement, implies that $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89026/discussion-between-nathaniel-mayer-and-daavid).